# How to type a tall / symbol?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, scaling, math-operators

Say I want

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[cl(V, q) =\left (\sum_{r=0}^{\infty} \bigotimes^r V\right)/\{v\otimes v = -q(v,v)\}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

How to make the "/" symbol longer to cover the height of the first expression?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
  \mathit{cl}(V, q) =
  \biggl(\sum_{r=0}^{\infty} \bigotimes^r V\biggr)
  \bigg/
  \bigl\{v\otimes v = -q(v,v)\bigr\}
\]
\end{document}
```

Several comments:

- don't use `\left\right` around summation and integration symbols, it produces way too large delimiters. (Better don't use them at all.)
- `cl` seems to be one math item hence it should be placed inside `\mathit` for a proper spacing. (You can use `\mathrm`, `\mathsf` etc. as well.)
- I made the `\{\}` in the last part a bit larger so that the set doesn't look so humble.

Comment: The only thing I'd change is to add a thinspace (`\,`) after the opening round parenthesis, to lessen the visual clash with the sum's subscript.

Answer (score 7):

Well you could use flexible brackets

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\[cl(V, q) =\left.\left (\sum_{r=0}^{\infty} \bigotimes^r V\right)\right/ \{ v\otimes v = -q(v,v)\}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

In any case you could use fixed brackets:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\[V \big/ \Big/ \bigg/  \Bigg/ \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of employing nested `\left ...\right` pairs, you could also use `\left( ... \middle) \right/` directives.

Comment: Just curious the notation $\left.$ does not show anything just acting as a paire of $\right /$, correct?

Comment: `\left.` is a 'white' counter-part of any `\right`. It's used for single felxible bracktes

Comment: @Mico Yes. AFAIK there is no difference in the output

Comment: @bloodworks Actually, `\left.` and `\right.` add a horizontal space of width `\nulldelimiterspace`.

Comment: @egreg indeed... never took a deeper look on this. But thats at least 1.2pt almost a half milli meter.. +1